# I am new to React, This is related to lifecycle of React

Tags: reactjs

Just want to know if I have one component and whenever state is changed what all lifeycle methods are called?
Also another Quetion is when i have two components and when a Parent state is updated what all lifecylce methods are called for Parent and Child.
THis Q is mainly to clear my confusion related to componentWillRecieveProp and Update lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

### `componentWillMount()`

> Invoked once, both on the client and server, immediately before the initial rendering occurs. If you call setState within this method, render() will see the updated state and will be executed only once despite the state change.

### `componentDidMount()`

> Invoked once, only on the client (not on the server), immediately after the initial rendering occurs. At this point in the lifecycle, you can access any refs to your children (e.g., to access the underlying DOM representation). The componentDidMount() method of child components is invoked before that of parent components.

### `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`

> Invoked when a component is receiving new props. This method is not called for the initial render.
>
> Use this as an opportunity to react to a prop transition before render() is called by updating the state using this.setState(). The old props can be accessed via this.props. Calling this.setState() within this function will not trigger an additional render.

### `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`

> Invoked before rendering when new props or state are being received. This method is not called for the initial render or when forceUpdate is used.
>
> Use this as an opportunity to return false when you're certain that the transition to the new props and state will not require a component update.

### `componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`

> Invoked immediately before rendering when new props or state are being received. This method is not called for the initial render.
>
> Use this as an opportunity to perform preparation before an update occurs.

### `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)`

> Invoked immediately after the component's updates are flushed to the DOM. This method is not called for the initial render.
>
> Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated.

### `componentWillUnmount()`

> Invoked immediately before a component is unmounted from the DOM.
>
> Perform any necessary cleanup in this method, such as invalidating timers or cleaning up any DOM elements that were created in componentDidMount.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you call `setState`, the following functions are called:

- `shouldComponentUpdate`

If this returns true

- `componentWillUpdate`
- `render`
- `componentDidUpdate`

If `shouldComponentUpdate` returns false, nothing will happen.

If your component has child components passing down props through it's state, only these children will re-render (with the extra function `componentWillReceiveProps` called for those componenents).

For more info: [Visualisation of the lifecycle](http://imgh.us/react-lifecycle.svg) and [React official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)